# Learning Scheme Macros. Help me write a define-syntax-rule

Tags: functional-programming, macros, scheme

I am new to Scheme Macros. If I just have one pattern and I want to combine the define-syntax and syntax-rules, how do I do that?

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules (from to)
    [(for i from x to y step body) ...]
    [(for i from x to y body) ...]))
```

If I just have one for, how do I combine the syntax definition and the rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In other words, you decided that `for` really only needs one pattern and want to write something like:

```
(defmacro (for ,i from ,x to ,y step ,body)
  ; code goes here
  )
```

There is nothing built-in to Scheme that makes single-pattern macros faster to write. The traditional solution is (surprise!) to write another macro.

I have used [`defsubst` from Swindle](http://barzilay.org/Swindle/misc-doc.html), and PLT Scheme [now ships with `define-syntax-rule`](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide/pattern-macros.html) which does the same thing. If you are learning macros, then writing your own `define-syntax-rule` equivalent would be a good exercise, particularly if you want some way to indicate keywords like "for" and "from". Neither `defsubst` nor `define-syntax-rule` handle those.

Comment: This is all correct, and I can also add that writing such a `define-synatx-rule` macro is a very simple case of macro-that-generates-macros.  But just in case you missed it, PLT *does* have a `define-syntax-rule` as part of the language.

(BTW, those "noise words" are called "keywords", and you're correct that the common definition for `define-syntax-rule` doesn't have a place for them -- this is fine, since keywords are usually used to distinguish multiple patterns.)

Comment: It's probably new since I last used PLT. Thanks for the terminology; I don't use keywords so I didn't know what they're called.